# What is the meaning and origin of the surname Nesselrothees?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, surnames

I am having trouble finding anything out about the surname Nesselrothees. My great grandmother was registered under the surname in 1840 England. Her father was Alexander Dorow Nesselrothees. He was apparently from Frankfurt.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE. You can find an introduction to our site in our [tour]. Could you please name your sources, e.g. for the origin of Alexander Dorow Nesselrothees?

Answer (score 2):

If the family origin is indeed Germany, the name *Nesselrothees* reminds me of the German nobel family of *Nesselrode*. There is an extensive Wikipedia article (in German) on this family: [*Nesselrode (Adelsgeschlecht)*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesselrode_(Adelsgeschlecht)). Please provide more information on your great-great-grandfather, e.g. by linking sources. If there is a sourced link to Germany, I can maybe help with further research ideas to connect the name to the family mentioned above. The family name *Nesselrode* comes from *Nessel* (“nettel”) and -*rodung*, an suffix meaning “clearing”. The place linked to the family origins is [*Nesselrath*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haus_Nesselrath), also referred to as *Nesselrode* in medieval times.

Answer (score 2):

1. The original spelling may have been "Nesselrath". A search for "Nesselr*" in the [Historic German addressbooks](http://adressbuecher.genealogy.net/) includes a number of Nesselrath entries, and some additional variants: Nesselrat, Nesselroda, Nesselrode, Nesselrodt, Nesselroth
2. Since "Nessel" is also a surname, consider that "Nesselrothees" may have been a hyphenated name. Although "Rothees" does not appear in the previously referenced database, Rothes does: thus "Nessel-Rothes".

A final consideration: there are 2 German cities named Frankfurt, and [a number of smaller placenames](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/name?name=frankfurt) that include Frankfurt in the name.

Answer (score -1):

It has taken me over 20 years to find my great grandmothers birth the reason being I have been looking for her under the surname Wolff which is the name she and her family were using on the 1851 English Census. I have since found 6 of her siblings registered under the name Nesselrothees. I have her birth certificate and have ordered some of the others.
I have 6 births and one death under the name Nesselrothees and maybe 4 births and 2 deaths under the name Wolff. Her fathers name on the 1851 census was Alexander Heinrich Wolff born Frankfurt on the Mein, occupation Professor of Piano Forte. He died in 1855. He was 20 years older than his wife and in saying that I can't find a marriage for them.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I also would like to encourage you to take the [tour].  Stack Exchange is not a forum -- it is a question-and-answer site.  Your post will be deleted because it is not an answer to the question you posted above -- if you want to ask a question about finding this marriage record, please ask a new question and copy this information into that question, using the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree that the information that you have provided here will be very useful as a new question about finding the marriage certificate (which may inadvertently turn up new leads). However, it does not qualify as an answer to the original question you asked here about the origin and meaning of the surname.

Comment: My 3x Great Grandfather is Alexander Heinrich Wolff, but have no information on his family. Were you ever able to find out the link between Wolff and Nesselrothees?